# Create SQL trigger for insert auto increment column in specific format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Here is the code as I tried to insert into table Task in TID column in this format "ADDDMMYYYYxxxx". The output value is NULL

```
create table Task
(
    TID nvarchar(50) default 'QA201712120000' 
);
go


create trigger insertTask
on Task
after insert as
begin
    update Task set TID=
    'QA' + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '') +
    RIGHT( '000' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR(4)) ,  4 ) 
end


insert into Task default values;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Mr @Maher.  Is there a problem with your sql code, that you could describe using text.  The title alone is not enough of a description.

Comment: I want  to insert into table Task in TID column in this format "ADDDMMYYYYxxxx"

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server

Comment: While we do need to know the vendor to help, one thing your current code does is update ALL records in the table. I doubt you want to do that.

Comment: There is only one column "TID" That i want to edit its value to be in this format "ADDDMMYYYYxxxx"

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with just one column. You are referencing scope_identity, so at a minimum you would need an ID column that is set to autogenerate an identity to have a value to grab And what happens if you have more than 9999 inserts on the same day? Then your value would no longer be unique.  There's a reason why it always a bad idea to have made up ids like this instead of using identities. Personally I woudl push back the requirement and say there is too great a risk to data integrity to do this.

Comment: Oh and do you need to start teh last four digits again on the next day instead of ever increasing them? That is totally different code. Still a bad idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my example code below.

```
create table Task
(
    ID int not null identity (1,1) primary key,
    TID nvarchar(50) default 'QA201712120000' 
);
go

create trigger insertTask
on Task
after insert as
begin
    update Task
    set TID = 'QA' + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '')
                   + RIGHT( '000' + CAST(inserted.ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
    from Task
    join inserted on inserted.ID = Task.ID;
end;
go

insert into Task default values;
insert into Task default values;
insert into Task default values;

select * from Task;
```

Features of this solution:

- Only updates the newly inserted records - *previous example updated
  the whole table*
- Applies the correct ID value on a per-record basis -
  *previous example used the global value derived from SCOPE_IDENTITY()*

Answer (score 0):

create TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_GenerateRegistrationNo] ON [dbo].[T_Registration]
    AFTER INSERT
AS

```
    DECLARE @regisId BIGINT ,
        @registrationNo VARCHAR(20)  
    SELECT  @regisId = regisId FROM inserted

    SELECT  @registrationNo=  'AUTO'+  RIGHT('0000000'
                                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @regisId),
                                                7)

     UPDATE  T_Registration SET  registrationNo = @registrationNo   WHERE   regisId = @regisId
```